# Cakephp3 prevent route to Wordpress blog by htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cakephp

This is the situation i'm facing with:

Assuming this folder structure:

- cakephp (main site)
- wordpress (site blog)

The main site was develop with CakePHP3 (mysite.com). I create a Wordpress blog in their own repo. So I want to redirect with htaccess url's like `mysite.com/en/blog` to another folder outside cake.

This is the htaccess file on the cakephp root, that handle all the request:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

I try adding something like this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /en/blog
RewriteRule ^/en/blog$ /path/to/wordpress [L]
```

To prevent cake handle this route, but i can make it work.

*I can make it work if a create subfolders inside cakephp webroot dir, and install wordpress inside it, but is not the best approach..*

Any ideas?

Thanks!