# htaccess for SSL for 2 websites

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp

I have a cakephp3 website and a wordpress website. in the root folder the .htaccess rewrites wordpress  http commands to https . However I also need my cakephp3 to redirect http to https . I cant do this for cakephp3. The SSL is set up. The below doesnt work as it redirects a https wrongly

```
# BEGIN SSL
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://crm.mydomain/$1 [R=301,L]  //cakephp3
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain//$1 [R=301,L]  //wordpress
# END SSL
```

I have looked at other websites like

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46958423/cakephp3-prevent-route-to-wordpress-blog-by-htaccess
http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/ssl/how-to-force-https-using-the-htaccess-file
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
Rewritebase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This doesnt work as is. Do I need to hardcode the actual domain instead of using the variables? I dont get an error buy I can access http request for the cakephp3 website . The wordpress works fine for http redirects

Comment: No, you don't. You should use this code in .htaccess each root folder for your web sites

Comment: Thanks for the reply and advice but as I said before the code given doesnt work! It doesnt redirect the cakephp website as I can still reference http://